# как правильно организовать MVC модель?

Tags: qt, mvc

Пишу учебное задание, пытаюсь написать некоторое подобие MVC. Пытаюсь разделить логику программы и интерфейса в разные классы. Соответственно, запилил классы `Controller` и `View`. `View` содержит нажатия всяких кнопок, считывание с полей, обновление содержимого меток и т.п. `Controller` же должен по идее инициировать запуск `View` и считывать получаемые значения для проведения операций над ними и передачи этого добра в модель. Я сделал вьюху элементом контроллера, вызываю её, но столкнулся с проблемой - а как, собственно получать из вьюхи данные? Т.е. например, я понимаю, что можно запустить `view->show()` и прочие методы вызывать из контроллера, но как обеспечить свободную работу с формой пользователю и при этом вовремя получать информацию о его действиях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так у вас слоты вьюхи и так срабатывают по событиям пользователя. И в этих слотах должны вызываться методы контроллера. А вот как раз в контроллере не должно быть вызовов методов вьюхи, иначе они получаются привязаны сильно. По событиям контроллера (по его сигналам) так же должна обновляться view.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы мне предлагаете взяться за программу "с другого конца" - т.е. контроллер сделать элементом вьюхи, а модель элементом контроллера, и вызывать методы контроллера согласно слотам? Т.е. доступ к модели из вьюхи надо будет тогда организовать из спецметода контроллера, чтобы не нарушить шаблон MVC, так?

Comment: Не так немного. У вас есть вью, модель и контроллер. События в системе происходят когда? Когда пользователь нажимает кнопки. Значит в слотах кнопок и вызываются методы контроллера. Модель у вас обновляется-читается когда? Иногда по нажатию кнопок - иногда в контроллере. Вот и вызывайте методы модели где-то в слотах, где-то в контроллере. Доступ к модели у вас организовывается в методах модели. (А не в контроллере) . Конетроллер тоже не элемент вьюхи (конечно можно завести и один объект контроллер -член класса вью) но этот объект для доступа к методам контроллера, и обработка данных только в ни

Comment: Только в методах контроллера. А так как надо стремится не заводить лишних членов класса - то контроллер все же лучше заводить локально в нужных методах, -завели по нажатию кнопки объект контроллер, запустили его метод обработка данных - (а в методе обработки вызвали метод модели данных "сохранить"-) в конце слота нажатия кнопки кнопки все сдохли, отработав свое.

Comment: А если организовать прямой доступ к модели из вьюхи, разве не нарушится сама концепция шаблона MVC? Обычно на схемах нет прямой стрелки от вьюхи к модели http://www.vr-online.ru/article/pattern/screen1.jpg

И ещё такой вопрос - я честно говоря не понял, если контроллер не делать членом класса вьюхи, а отдельным и независимым объектом, то как к нему тогда обращаться-то?

Comment: Не членом класса - а локальной переменной в методе класса. Зачем заводить член класса, если он не отображает состояние объекта ? (А контроллер не хранит и не отображает состояние вьюхи). По поводу прямого доступа из вью к данным - у вас не будет прямого доступа к данным! Модель - это не данные, это класс, который отвечает за их хранение-запись-чтение. В этом классе есть метод "записать" вы его из вью вызываете. А уже в этом методе, скрытое от вью осуществляется запись куда надо. В бд, файл, рееестр или внутренние переменные модели. Таким образом работа с данными вынесена отдельно.

Comment: теперь все встало на свои места, большое спасибо